# how to use awk to separate string contains space in linux

Tags: linux, awk

I am new to using awk i want to separate string contains spaces.
`vboxmanage list vms` this is my command and its output is below

```
"VMOne" {5559eb92-2665-4c52-a75d-b57c248c74db}
"VM Second" {9bc754f8-4dfd-44e5-9469-dd824d438832}
```

my expected output is `VMOne;VM Second` below is some thing i have tried

```
vboxmanage list vms | awk '{print $1,";"}' | sed 's/"//g' | awk -vORS="" '1'
```

but, it gives me output like `VMOne ;VM ;` it cuts the `second` word and add a space before `;`

any suggestion will helpfull thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F\" '{ printf (NR > 1 ? ";%s" : "%s"), $2 } END { if (NR) print "" }' file
```

Output:

```
VMOne;VM Second
```

- `if (NR)` is optional if expected input always has lines. You can also remove the `END` block completely if you don't need to terminate the output with newline on the end.

Comment: Another way in awk `awk -F\" '{printf $2";"}END{print "\b "}' file`

Comment: @Jidder - never use input data where the `printf` format field belongs unless you have a very specific need, can fully control the data, and fully understand all the implications. What if the input data in this case contained a `%` character in `$2`? Use `printf "%s;", $2` rather than `printf $2";"`. I wouldnt add the `;` and then try to remove it anyway though, just don't add it in the first place, and adding a backspace does not remove the character, it just hides it when printed to a terminal by adding yet another undesirable character.

Comment: @konsolebox +1, FWIW I'd have written the body part as `printf "%s%s", (NR > 1 ? ";" : ""), $2` as IMHO that's clearer and it lets you specify the format string in just one place and separate the formatting from the content in case you need to modify it, but it's probably mainly just a preference given the style I'm used to.

Comment: @EdMorton fair enough, just though i'd give an alternate way, do you know any way of not replacing the character with a space ? Also i didnt realise it would do that if it contained a `%`, so thanks for the info.

Comment: @Jidder - do it the way konsolebox did, i.e. put the separator before the text rather than after it. There's only 2 acceptable patterns here - when you do not know the max value in the [implicit] loop like when reading lines `for (...) {printf "%s%s", (idx>1?OFS:""), string} print ""` or when you do like when reading fields: `for (...) {printf "%s%s", string, (idx<max?OFS:ORS)}`. Note no need for a later `print ""` in that last case so IMHO that's slightly preferable when it can be used.

Comment: @Jidder - by the way, to be clear: `printf "abc\b "` does not replace the `c` with a space, it prints all of `abc\b `. It's only on your screen that the `c` LOOKS like it's been replaced with a space since that's the way your terminal interprets the `\b` character but if you saved that output to a file and did a grep for `ab ` (`ab` followed by a space) you would not find it. Adding that `\b ` is actually corrupting the output by adding invisible control characters. If we wanted to obfuscate our text we could all just use Microsoft products :-).

Comment: @EdMorton I've only ever used it to print things to screen so i haven't noticed. I have just looked it up though and it looks like you can configure it to not output `^H` if you really wanted to.

Comment: @Jidder - no, you can't print anything to remove characters that have already been printed. If you want to "print" a string and then remove the last character from it, then you need to do something like this `foo=sprintf("%s",string); sub(/.$/,foo); printf "%s", foo` instead of `printf "%s", string; print "\b"` or any other variation.